# google vision OCR TEXT_DETECTION returns empty response

Tags: c++, rest, google-vision, rad-studio

I am trying to use Google Vision API to detect text from an image, but the JSON response is empty

I've built a Windows VCL C++ Builder app with RADSutdio 10.3 that selects an existing image, turns it into a BASE64 string and sends it as the image content as shown below:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE"
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using RESTClient, RESTRequest and RESTResponse components to achieve this. It works perfectly fine, and I get the response and manipulate it as I want.

The problem comes when I try to replicate this with a Android 32-bit Multi-Device Form with RADStudio 10.4, I get a 200 status code but my response is:

`{}`

This is my code:

```
String json1="{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"content\":\""+BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE+"\"},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"TEXT_DETECTION\"}]}]}";
RESTClient1->ResetToDefaults();
RESTClient1->Accept = "application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,";
RESTClient1->AcceptCharset = "UTF-8, *;q=0.8";
RESTClient1->BaseURL = "https://vision.googleapis.com";
RESTClient1->HandleRedirects = true;
RESTClient1->RaiseExceptionOn500 = false;
String APIkey = "MY_APIKEY";
RESTRequest2->Resource = "v1/images:annotate?key=" + APIkey;
RESTRequest2->Client = RESTClient1;
RESTRequest2->Response = RESTResponse1;
RESTRequest2->SynchronizedEvents = false;
RESTResponse1->ContentType = "application/json";
RESTRequest2->Params->AddItem();
RESTRequest2->Params->Items[0]->Value = json1;
RESTResponse1->RootElement = "responses[0].textAnnotations[0]";
RESTRequest2->Execute();
```